# Multiple dynamic input character restriction

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form where users can add inputs dynamically. The sum of the inputs character length shouldn't be higher than 500 and I can not get rid of it in the correct way.

Current javascript code looks like this:

```
 $('.group[data-maxchar] .add-item-input').on('keyup paste', function () {
    var group = $(this).closest('.group[data-maxchar]');
    var maxChar = parseInt($(this).closest('.group[data-maxchar]').attr('data-maxchar'));
    var remainingChar = parseInt(group.find('.counter').text());
    var str = $(this).val();
    var length = str.length;

    if (remainingChar < 1) {
        $(this).val(str.substr(0, maxChar));
    }

    updateCounters(group);
});
```

On first input added I can I'm able to insert 500 characters correctly and then if I try to paste ot type more text it get stopped and I do not exceed it.

Unfortunately if I add more inputs I see the counter going negative and I'm able to write text...

I'm pretty sure the error is in this part of the control:

```
if (remainingChar < 1) {
    $(this).val(str.substr(0, maxChar)); //here
}
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is with `on` event. Check the [jquery api](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Proper usage is  `$('.group[data-maxchar]').on('keypress paste', '.add-item-input', function () {`. Then function going to be triggered for each element in group.

Also use `keypress` instead of `keyup` because you want to handle only printable characters.

[See demo](https://jsfiddle.net/joeyczech/5ygh1qn1/3/)